# should data in redux be immutable within dump component in react?

Tags: reactjs, immutability, redux, immutable.js

in redux reducer I get json data object and use "state.set" in order to use it later on:

```
return state.set('data', document.somedata);
```

1) I try to understand if I should use immutablejs (fromJS) at this point?

2) If I do, how do I pass the data into the dump component from the container and so on?

3) does this mean that I have to use toJS all the time in each dump component in order to work with my data? (print, iterate and so on, but not mutate it)

Comment: If you're going to use Immutable.js, it's highly recommended to go all in and use only the APIs they provide. If not, just use plain JavaScript functions without mutation.

Comment: @Kujira do you have any recommendation on how to work within the component with immutable.js? maybe tutorials and such. for example - print a list of todo from immutable object - because i had some problems working with immutable js or passing the data into the dump component and using it within the view/component.

Comment: Immutable.js should be very straight forward, as only difference would be when you are setting or getting. Therefore passing data would be exactly same with or without Immutable.js, and the APIs to traverse is straight forward [as documented on their site](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/). If you don't feel familiar with React and React-Redux yet, I'll suggest you to try making the app without Immutable.js first. In that case, [Dan Abramov's Getting Started with Redux video](https://egghead.io/series/getting-started-with-redux) is a perfect video to have todo working with React-Redux.

Comment: Thanks @Kujira I was able to work all the way with immutablejs and print the data in the component via it's api. woohoo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I did use fromJS at this point, because i really want to work with immutablejs and think it's the right way. plus, ideally you should be using immutable all the way, and as much as you can.

2) Just end up passing the data via props and `data={data}`

3) no, i did not had to use toJS even once and at the end i was able to pass the immutable data all the way to the dump component and use the immutablejs api to print the data `data.getIn(['this_is', 'path_to_data']).map(function(data, index) { return data.get('value')... })`